# ArgumentException from DataRow.Item() in Turkish Window server 2008 installtion

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, .net-2.0, windows-server-2008-r2, turkish

Our software was installed on (customer site) Window Server 2008 R2 Foundation in Turkey (So locale is set to Turkish, and thus all menus and messages are displayed in Turkish). We are using SQL server 2005 express. The database collation is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI` (as in our other English installed sites).

Our code query the database with a simple query: `select * form tableName where callid='variable'` (callid is our primary key, however the column name in the database is CallID, column type is `varchar(60)`), using `SqlDataAdapter.Fill()` method to fill our untyped `DataSet`.

We yield the `DataRow` object from `DataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]`. We pass this `DataRow` object to other methods and we use [DataRow.Item (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/146h6tk5.aspx) to get the columns values. We have several columns that we get their values this way with no problems. However for one particular column we get

```
ArgumentException: <column name> column does not belong to table Table
```

This column is our callid column!
When we change the column name in database to callid, or CalliD we don't get the exception.
I've seen this article called [Introduce the Turkish I issue](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/qingsongyao/archive/2009/02/13/introduce-the-turkish-i-issue.aspx) and as I understand it the issue the article address is when collation = TURKISH_CI_AS.

What am I missing here? 
I'd appreciate any helpful input.

Thanks, Ilan

Comment: You've said when you change the column name *to* `callid` or `CalliD` it works - what is it now?

Comment: @JonSkeet I've mentioned that in question - CallID.

Comment: Thanks - not sure why I couldn't see it before. I'm sure this *is* the "Turkish I problem" - just not at the database side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the problem isn't occurring on the *database* side at all, but when the *local* code (`DataSet`) is looking for your column.

The simplest fix is probably to use the column *ordinal* value instead of the name. For diagnostic purposes, I suggest you look through the column names returned by [`DataTable.Columns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.columns.aspx) and try various approaches to match the name in a case/culture-insensitive way. If you don't know the ordinal up-front, you might want to find it that way dynamically, if getting the `DataSet` to find it fails :(

Comment: Your guess is indeed correct, the problem isn't occurring on the _database_ side. I've finally got a Turkish install on a local PC and found out that queries with `select * from tableName` yields the mentioned exception. However when explicitly setting the column names (`select columnA, columnB from tableNAme`) in the query it works fine.